# how to overwrite a line of text in a text file in python

Tags: python

```
name email phonenumber
eric example@gmail.com 01381031
tuna tuna@gmail.com 1571051
```

above is the personal_details.txt

```
def personal(userid):
    print("Modify personal details")
    newemail = input("Enter your new email: ")
    newphone = input("Enter your new phone:")
    with open("personal_details.txt", "r+") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.split()
            if userid == line[0]:
                file.seek(0)
                file.write(" " + newemail + " " + newphone)
                file.truncate()
```

I am creating profile system which users can modify the details.
I wanna overwrite the text in line[2] and line[3] of the files but it keeps overwriting the whole files. Im quite new to python so I really need some helps to figure out this problem.

Comment: `file.seek(0)` sets the reference point to the beginning of the file instead of the line.

Answer (score 0):

First copy the text to a new variable and use .replace to replace the desired words and then you can override the textfile